# How to display and play fetching image and audio form server in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to i phone programming.I have upload image and audio in server.After that i am fetching image and audio form server.I am getting response form server like this below in xml format.

```
<image>./uploads/45/Image/123.jpg</image>
```

Audio

```
<audio>./uploads/45/Audio/123.mp3</audio>
```

Using NSXmlparser i parse the data and using below code i am trying to display image in imageview.But i am not able to display image.Can any body tell me correct way how to display image and how to play audio using above audio url

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://./uploads/45/Image/123.jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
```

Comment: Is that the actual URL you are using or are you just abbreviating it?

Comment: this is "./uploads/45/Image/123.jpg" actual url.This "http://./uploads/45/Image/123.jpg"Just modified "http://"

Comment: So the actual URL you are using is something like "www.domain.com/uploads/45/Image/123.jpg"   ?